# Python - Can updating 2.7.6 to 2.7.9 cause any problems/conflicts?

Tags: python, version-control, version, updates, conflict

Question: I'm a new python user. I'm currently using v2.7.6 in a tied relations with other systems and files written in different languages. Does updating to v2.7.9 might cause any issues?
Any hidden conflicts for using py files that were written in 2.7.6 and/or using files written in other languages?

Could is a bit of explanation on why it might cause issue/why it couldn't.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Minor/bugfix releases aren't supposed to break anything. Something can always potentially go wrong, but your risk is probably minimally. Note that your risk does increase with the more libraries and third-party integration you use, but it still is very small.

Also, somewhat of a nitpick, but there isn't a concept of a `.py` file "written" in 2.7.6.

`.py` files are just `.py` files and are executed with the 2.7.6 python interpreter, or 2.7.9, and so on.

You can find the list of changes in 2.7.9 here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/

Answer (score 1):

This should not cause any problems.  The changes are here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279rc1/.  A few more things will work.  The only thing I see that won't work any more are changes due to a security flaw in the old version.  You probably don't want that to still work.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is always a chance that upgrading a system component could cause errors. The Python devs do, however, take backwards compatibility fairly seriously.

If this is a serious concern you should make sure your software has adequate unit tests, and run them on the updated Python before installing it on your production system.

Answer (score 0):

It should be unlikely to cause any problems. A Python version has the format `major.minor.bugfix`. Changes in `bugfix` shouldn't change how any programs work, unless it makes them work correctly where they weren't before. Changes in `minor` shouldn't require you to change your programs much, but you might have to upgrade libraries. Changes in `major` are definitely backwards incompatible, but thankfully not that common. You're only likely to encounter problems if your programs have lots and lots of dependencies.